# Why speech recognition not recognize full speech in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I tried to use the following code to recognize a 5 min audio

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment
import wavio
from scipy.io import wavfile

test_file = open("test.txt", "w+")
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("001.mp3")
sound.export("001.wav", format="wav")

AUDIO_FILE = "001.wav"

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)                   
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(text)
            test_file.write(text+". ")
        except:
            print('Run again')
```

But it only return the very first couple words: "listening diagnostic pretest page 143", do you guys know why it didn't recognize the whole audio?

Comment: are you sure it's wavio instead of wav.io?

Comment: Have you considered using the mic as the input for your speech recognition system?  `with sr.Microphone() as source:`

Comment: I imported wavio but didn’t actually use it in the following code, so it shouldn’t be the problem I think.

Comment: The goal was to transcribe audio that we get through phone calls, so using the mic as the input is probably not going to solve the issue:(